# Integrating prolog into other environments

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm using Prolog for an academic project. I wanted to know if there is a way for Prolog to interact with other programming languages. What I want is an easy input/output redirection of Prolog question and answers.

I'm aware that Prolog can call C functions in some Prolog implementations. i.e. SWI Prolog.

What I need is a simple input/output redirection of Prolog questions and the answer that user provides.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any true requirement for a foreign language interface for your task: use Prolog IO, it's easy to use and efficient. You could also start with just support from [protocol](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.36%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/protocol.html%27%29%29)/1. Just a KISS advice...

A foreign language interface it's mandatory when you need something implemented in that other language.

SWI-Prolog [C++ interface](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/pl2cpp.html) it's much easier to use than C counterpart, and allows both extending the language with really easy builtins' coding as well as embedding the engine in a standalone 'main'. And these 2 aspects can cohexist gracefully: say for a fast prototype just we implement the builtins, and use the REPL top level, while a full blown application can start the engine to be used as logic engine, and submit the (hopefully tested via REPL) queries in background.

Then there is [JPL](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/jpl.pl) to interface SWI-Prolog and Java. I know little about it... I've seen some problem reported on the SWI-Prolog mailing list, due (mainly) to the complexity of different threading models. But certainly it's working.

An interesting development is occurring to make available the IDE into Eclipse ([PDT](http://sewiki.iai.uni-bonn.de/research/pdt/start), Prolog Development tools). I think they use their own Java interface. Currently could be a better choice than JPL.

But the most interesting interface SWI-Prolog can propose today it's the HTTP server infrastructure. If you known WEB client development (HTML/JavaScript/XML/RDF) you have plenty of tools to split your design in MVC Client/Server. Prolog runs a Web Service, and a Rich Client interacts with end user. This architecture make your application ready to run locally as well in the wild.

Please see the relevant [How To](http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/) section...Is not a simple task, but (IMHO) a very rewarding and long standing one.

Answer (score 2):

SWI-Prolog can interface with C (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/clib.html), C++ (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/pl2cpp.html), C# (http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.html) and Python (http://code.google.com/p/pyswip/). Furthermore, you can communicate with Prolog via e.g., external files.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Amzi Prolog + Logic Server](http://www.amzi.com/products/amzi_prolog_logic_server.htm) - its purpose is to make prolog programs accessible as componentto other conventional languages.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Prolog distribution you are using. As previously commented SWI-Prolog provides different interfaces for the most common uses like C, C++, databases, HTTP, XML and others.
The [Ciao](http://www.ciaohome.org) distribution can be also useful for what you are looking for. In this case is C so check out this link [Ciao Prolog and C](http://www.ciaohome.org/docs/ciao/foreign_interface_doc.html)